# Create empty pandas dataframe from pandera DataFrameModel

Tags: python, pandas, pandera

Is there a way to create an **empty pandas dataframe** from a **pandera schema**?

Given the following schema, I would like to get an empty dataframe as shown below:

```
from pandera.typing import Series, DataFrame

class MySchema(pa.DataFrameModel):
    state: Series[str]
    city: Series[str]
    price: Series[int]

def get_empty_df_of_schema(schema: pa.DataFrameModel) -> pd.DataFrame:
    pass

wanted_result = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['state', 'city', 'price']
).astype({'state': str, 'city': str, 'price': int})
wanted_result.info()
```

Desired result:

```
Index: 0 entries
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   state   0 non-null      object
 1   city    0 non-null      object
 2   price   0 non-null      int64
```

---

Edit:

Found a working solution:

```
def get_empty_df_of_pandera_model(model: [DataFrameModel, MetaModel]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    schema = model.to_schema()
    column_names = list(schema.columns.keys())
    data_types = {column_name: column_type.dtype.type.name for column_name, column_type in schema.columns.items()}
    return pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names).astype(data_types)
```

Answer (score 1):

The current pandera docs have small section on [pandas data types](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dataframe_schemas.html#get-pandas-data-types)

This suggests the following solution:

```py
import pandera as pa
import pandas as pd

def empty_dataframe_from_model(Model: pa.DataFrameModel) -> pd.DataFrame:
    schema = Model.to_schema()
    return pd.DataFrame(columns=schema.dtypes.keys()).astype(
        {col: str(dtype) for col, dtype in schema.dtypes.items()}
    )
```

Comment: This might not work. For example, for schema column defined as `foo: datetime.date`, `astype()` raises an exception of unknown type `date`. The solution in the question using `dtype.type.name` does work.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible to create empty pandas dataframe using pandera schema with the help of the function `schema.to_dataframe()`.

Here is the updated version of the function `get_empty_df_of_schema`

```
def get_empty_df_of_schema(schema: pa.DataFrameModel) -> pd.DataFrame:
    row_empty = schema({}).astype(str).iloc[0]
    return pd.DataFrame(columns=row_empty.index).astype(row_empty.to_dict())
```

Also, have a look at dataframes schemas through the following [link](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dataframe_schemas.html)

Comment: thx for your input, but got a TypeError when I tried MySchema({})

Comment: There is no mention of a `.to_dataframe` method in the documentation. You're also not using this method in your example, so I'm unclear on why you bring this method up. Finally, the example you provide is very hard to follow without additional explanation, and will likely not work out of the box.